# How to get my wells to align vertically

Tags: css

I've got a page that shows 3 wells within another well.  http://visualhaggard.org/illustrations/2.  There is a span5 on the left and span 7 on the right.  The illustration on the right is in one well while the 2 supplements on the right are each in their own well.  The header portions, "Other illustrations...", are not in those wells.  If I move the headers within the wells, the wells become offset with the bottom one about 20px to the right of the top one, like so:

[image: image of offset wells]

The following description is from my local environment, not what's pictured in the link:

The wells sit in a normal bootstrap span7

And here is the styling for the supplement wells:

```
.well-associated-thumbnails {
  height:250px;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border_color: black;
}
```

Here's the code from the well on top:

```
<div class="span12 well-associated-thumbnails">
    <h5>Other Illustrations from <%= @novel_name %></h5>
    <% @related_illustrations_by_novel.each_slice(4) do |set| %>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <% set.each do |illustration| %>
          <div class="span3 ">
            <div align="center"><%= link_to image_tag(illustration.aws_image_thumbnail_url), illustration %>
                <br />
                <span style="font-size:x-small;">
                    <%= illustration.short_name %>
                </span>
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <br />
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And this is the well on the bottom:

```
<div class="span12 well-associated-thumbnails">
    <h5>Other Illustrations with similar Tags:</h5>
    <% @related_illustrations_by_tags.each_slice(4) do |set| %>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <% set.each do |illustration| %>
                <div class="span3 ">
                    <div align="center"><%= link_to image_tag(illustration.aws_image_thumbnail_url), illustration %>
                        <br />
                        <span style="font-size:x-small;">
                            <%= illustration.short_name %><br />
                            <%= link_to illustration.edition.novel.name, illustration.edition.novel %><br />
                        </span>
                    </div>
                <br />
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
        <br />
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Can anyone advise on why the wells get messed up when I put the headers inside of them?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS reset or a simple * { margin:0; padding: 0; }?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply changed `<div class="span12 well-associated-thumbnails">` to `<div class="well well-associated-thumbnails">` in the necessary locations.